# Loopback testing with memory as datasource

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to use the memory-connector as a datasource when doing integration testing. But it seems to always connect to the mongodb-datasource.

One major hack i have done is to change the datasource for each model to memory. But there must be a better way to do this. I'm running my tests from a gulp-task. My roflmao model-memory-hack:

```
var models = require('../server/model-config.json');
  for (var key in models) {
    var model = loopback.getModel(key);
    loopback.configureModel(model, {dataSource: memory});
  }
}
```

Is there any way to change the datasource for the app? Or do i have to change the datasource for each individual model..?

A way of doing this is to change the environment variable during testing, but so far, no luck.. I'm doing this with the gulp-task preprocess.

Hopefully by changing the environment variable, it would use datasources.integrationtesting.js, in which i have memory as a datasource.

My gulp-task:

```
return gulp.src('integration-tests/*.js')
.pipe($.preprocess({context: {NODE_ENV: 'integrationtesting'}}))
.pipe($.mocha())
```

I'm using:

- loopback-testing
- gulp-mocha

Appreciate any comments.. : )

Comment: What would fix this is to be able to change the NODE_ENV during testing...

Answer (score 8):

I think what you're looking for are [environment-specific configuration files](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Environment-specific+configuration). Basically, you just create a datasource with the same name, but different implementations in different environments. Your `datasources.json` file would be the default, but `datasources.development.json` would be used if `NODE_ENV` was set to `development`.

From that linked page, you might have this in datasources.json:

```
{
  db: {
    connector: 'mongodb',
    database: 'myapp',
    user: 'myapp',
    password: 'secret'
  }
}
```

And this in datasources.development.json:

```
{
  db: {
    connector: 'memory'
  }
}
```

Comment: As explained, i fire up the tests in a gulp task. I try to change the environment to "test" to allow for environment-specific configuration, but it doesn't seem to use the test-configs..